# Cordova/PhoneGap posting to php and storing returned data on device

Tags: php, android, ajax, cordova

I am looking to be able to have my Cordova/PhoneGap 3.0 app, connect to a database and retrieve user information given a particular username to query data for. Then I also want to store the returned information on the device for future access.

I imagine that I would need to pass the uername and password entered in the app, to an AJAX post method, that links to a php script that takes the input and queries the database, then returns the information I need... But im not sure as to how I will go about doing that because I've never used AJAX post methods to a php script to return information.

As for storing it, I have heard that there is somewhat of a SQL database present on the phonegap cordova framework? I may be wrong on that one, maybe it was a hack I saw at some point, but I am just looking to see how I could go about storing and calling upon stored variables in the applicaion.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this with PhoneGap, but I've done some work on something similarish using another cross-platform mobile framework, so I thought I'd add some comments --

First, I don't think storing the returned data on the device is necessarily a good idea, because if the data can be edited, how will you make sure it will stay in sync with the server?  Easier just to re-obtain it when you need it.

Secondly, when I did this, I ended up writing an actual login API in the PHP script that would return sessionID, which would get stored on the phone, then I could send sessionID back when the logged in session was required to avoid saving passwords (and what if password changes after they enter password?) or repeatedly asking for passwords.

Thirdly, I'm not sure how PhoneGap works, but I had difficulty getting it all to work together due to cross-domain request problems (especially with post.)  You'll probably at least have to part of what I did, which is add headers to your php scripts:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
```

Forth, I recommend looking into Restful.  You'll probably at the least want your PHP to return the results in json.